# Take value from cell for A(X) excel

Tags: excel

It is possible to retrieve the value from cell A in this way? Referring to an index entered in another cell?

For B5 == 3 I expects C5 to be FISH.

[image]

Comment: `=INDEX(A:A,B5)`.

Comment: @BigBen I use other language in excel and had to use ";" =INDEX(A:A;B5) but it work, Thanks.